# Get Product Attributes of a Product under a specific category Woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product category archive page and i wanted to get all product attributes assigned to the products under that category.

my attribute name is 'pa_brands'

so i have this code

```
  <?php
    $brand_terms = get_terms(array(
      'taxonomy'   => 'pa_brands',
      'hide_empty' => true,
    ));
  ?>
```

but this returns all product attribute "brands" there are attributes that are specically assigned to a product under a category, any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any category, attributes may differ as per product. So, you will need to loop for each product to get each products' attributes.

You can get all products for that category and loop for them. In the loop you can write this to get product attributes

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
```

Here, product is an object of product.

---

You can get all proucts in category by this:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'product_cat' => 'hoodie' );
```

Then, for each product you will have to loop and get attributes of it. Because, without looping you don't have a way to collect attributes for all of them.

Comment: this is all happening before the loop, and i am on the product category page

Comment: Edited my comment